# Using embedded firebird database with .NET

Tags: firebird, embedded-database

I want to use Embedded FireBird with .NET 3.5. I have few queries:

(1) Are there any new developments done on the embedded version by the FireBird community?

(2) Are there any database file repair & optimize (shrink etc.) features in it?

(3) Does it supports Triggers, Foreign Keys, PL/SQL type of things etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. The Embedded version is like a normal Firebird but encapsulated in a DLL and with some minor limitations. The Firebird Team just released some days ago the 2.5 version of SuperServer, Classic and Embedded flavors. More info at [Embedded Firebird Server](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) and [Firebird website](http://www.firebirdsql.org/).
2. There are tools to repair and optimize databases. Check [How to repair a corrupt Firebird database](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq324/)
3. Firebird is SQL:2003 conformant as stated in [Firebird: SQL Conformance](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=engine&id=SQL_conformance&nosb=1). It has triggers, foreiggn keys and stored procedures.

Hope that helps

Comment: FibPlus and FlameRobin come to my mind right now, but there are surely more out there.

Answer (score 3):

> (1) Are there any new developments
>   done on the embedded version by the
>   FireBird community?

Yes, both the embedded and the client-server version are very active projects.
Using the same embedded version dll for ADO.NET for example, you can use the most recent version of the firebird engine dlls, even if the ADO.NET Firebird provider is not build for that version, but for a previous.
Check the issue tracker here: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

> (2) Are there any database file repair
>   & optimize (shrink etc.) features in
>   it?

Yes, as described here: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq324/. You need to install the client-server version of firebird to use GFIX and GBAK from the command line. It is just a few megabytes.
Firebird does not have a "Compacting" feauture to shrink the database. You need to backup and then restore the database to do this. However you can use a firebird database for years without backup/restore (if you are lucky and the hard disk does not die). The only thing that you might need to do is to recalculate all indeces selectivity as described here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2005/03/improving-query-performance-through.html

> (3) Does it supports Triggers, Foreign
>   Keys, PL/SQL type of things etc.?

Yes. The 2.5 version of the embedded engine also supports accessing the same database file from different proccess at the same time.